# inheriting from class of specialized self?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

Is this valid C++?

```
template<class category>
class any_iterator : public any_iterator<void>
{ 
public:
        typedef any_iterator<void> any_iter_void;

        any_iterator() : any_iter_void() {}
};
template<>
class any_iterator<void>
{ 
public:
        typedef any_iterator<void> any_iter_void;

        any_iterator() {}
        void foo() {};
};

int main() {
    any_iterator<int> a;
    a.foo();
}
```

MSVC10 accepts it with no errors/warnings on `\WALL`, but [gcc-4.5.1](http://ideone.com/THHNh) complains:

> prog.cpp:3:5: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class any_iterator'
>   prog.cpp:2:11: error: declaration of 'class any_iterator'
>   prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   prog.cpp:21:11: error: 'class any_iterator' has no member named 'foo'
>   prog.cpp: In constructor 'any_iterator::any_iterator() [with category = int]':
>   prog.cpp:20:27:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:7:44: error: type 'any_iterator' is not a direct base of 'any_iterator'

Can someone quote the standard showing if this should or should not compile?  I think this is a bug in MSVC.

As a note, I know the correct thing to do is to declare the class, specialize the root, *then* define the general case, and that's what I'll do to my code, but I was wondering which compiler is wrong here?

Comment: MSVC's lack of two-phase name lookup strikes again.

Comment: Instead of using a specialization for your base class, why not use a different class altogether?

Comment: MSVC's implementation seems far handier IMO.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The (real) classes form a hierarchy, of which users may add types (they're iterator categories).  As such, `any_iterator<void>` makes sense as the root of everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inherit from a type, that type must be complete. A little rearranging solves things:

```
template<class category>
class any_iterator;

template<>
class any_iterator<void>
{ 
public:
    typedef any_iterator<void> any_iter_void;

    any_iterator() { }
    void foo() { }
};

template<class category>
class any_iterator : public any_iterator<void>
{ 
public:
    typedef any_iterator<void> any_iter_void;

    any_iterator() : any_iter_void() { }
};

int main()
{
    any_iterator<int> a;
    a.foo();
}
```

---

Token standard quotes:

C++11, §10/2:

> The type denoted by a *base-type-specifier* shall be a class type that is not an incompletely defined class; this class is called a *direct base class* for the class being defined.

§9.2/2:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*.

Comment: Heh, and 3 votes too.  `Can someone quote the standard...` and `the correct thing to do is to declare the class, specialize the root, then define the general case...`

Comment: You want a standard quote saying that a type must be complete in order to derive from it? Isn't that common sense?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, I thought.  You can normally derive from a template type that isn't yet specialized can't you? As long as it's specialized before the derived type is instantiated?

Comment: @Mooing : It doesn't need to be specialized, but it needs a complete definition. When doing `class any_iterator : public any_iterator<void>` without a prior complete definition of `any_iterator<void>`, `any_iterator` itself is not yet complete (no opening `{` muchless closing `}`) so it cannot be specified as a base class.

Comment: @ildjarn "_You want a standard quote saying that a type must be complete in order to derive from it?_" It must be complete, but **when** must it be complete?

Comment: @curiousguy : When you specify it as the base class for a class definition, as stated in the §10/2 quote. (The standard quotes were edited into my answer after that comment.)

Comment: @ildjarn It's more complicated actually (remember, this is C++). What you say is correct only for non-template subclassing. The standard quote seems incomplete.

Comment: @curiousguy : Instantiations and complete definitions are two different things. What I said absolutely applies to templates.

Comment: @ildjarn "_What I said absolutely applies to templates._" Wrong. It sometimes applies to templates, but obviously does not apply to deriving from a dependant type. The quote in **meaningless** in this case. The quoted text should be changed.

Comment: @curiousguy : If you'd like to stop embarrassing yourself, you'd actually back up what you're saying -- I have standard quotes and proper definitions (and compiler errors), you have a misguided, baseless rant. (BTW, `any_iterator<void>` is not a template.)

Comment: @ildjarn Is "rant" the code word for "I don't understand what you are saying, so shut up"?

Comment: @curiousguy : No, it's the code word for "you're unable to back up anything you're saying so why bother?"

Comment: @ildjarn I don't even understand what the standard quoted text means: is it about template class definition? template class instantiation?

Comment: @ildjarn Again what does the (badly written, BTW) quoted text means in case of a dependant type? This must be fixed.

Comment: Are you still not able to explain what the quoted text means when applied to a dependant type? Who is "ranting"?

Answer (score 0):

10/2:

> The type denoted by a base-type-speciﬁer shall be a class type that is not an incompletely deﬁned class

It is one manifestation of *the* bug of MSVC: its lack of two-phase name resolution.

Comment: "_its lack of two-phase name resolution._" not just 2-phases lookup, it probably implements old-style templates-as-macro "semantics"

Comment: @curiousguy: Since the code compiles, that means it saves the template instantiation for last though.