# Handling class inheritance from specialized instance of self in SWIG

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, swig, template-specialization

I have some code that compiles and works fine in C++ (as long as I forward declare the generic template class, then the specialized instance, and then define the generic template class - see [inheriting from class of specialized self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422488/inheriting-from-class-of-specialized-self)).   When I try to use SWIG to add C# bindings to the class, however, it either crashes SWIG or doesn't include the methods from the inherited class.  I believe this is only possible in C++11, but I'm not sure as I haven't tried this with an older compiler.

Here's a toy example:

```
template <typename T, int N = 0> class A;

template <typename T> class A<T, 0>
{
public:
    A() : mFoo(NULL)    {}
    virtual ~A()        {}

    T* getFoo() { return mFoo; }

protected:
    T* mFoo;
};

template <typename T, int N = 0> class A : public A<T, 0>
{
public:
    A() : A<T, 0>(), mBar(N)    {}
    virtual ~A()                {}

    int getBar() const { return mBar; }

protected:
    int mBar;
};
```

In a program, I can then instantiate an instance of `A<char,10>` (for example), and have access to mFoo and mBar, or just instantiate an instance of A and only have access to mFoo.   I can also use methods with parameters like

```
void baz(A<T, 0>* anyA)
```

and the method will accept `A<T, 0>` or `A<T, n>` instances.

For context and explanation, this pattern works well for containers that can be either dynamic or fixed size.  If they are dynamic, you can just instantiate it as a `A<T, 0>` and not have the overhead of inheritance, etc. or you can have a fixed-sized container (`A<T, N>` where N > 0) that does use inheritance, but has access to all the "base" class methods, can override them as needed, and still be accepted as a parameter for methods that accept either dynamic or fixed-sized instances of the container.

However, when I try to use SWIG so that I can use this class in other languages, I run into issues.

At first, I tried something like:

```
%template(tA) A<char, 0>;
```

but this causes SWIG to crash (at least in version 3.0.0 that I'm currently using).

Next, thinking that, like all template inheritance in SWIG, I need to have an existing template for the base class as well as the inheritor class (if both are templated anyway).  So I tried

```
%template(tABase) A<char, 0>;
%template(tA) A<char>;
```

This also causes SWIG to crash.

So, I tried to be a little clever and take advantage of SWIGS ability to use a "nameless" template for classes that are inherited from and did something like:

```
%template() A<char, 0>;
%template(tA) A<char>;
```

This avoids the crash and I get an output of the tA class, but it only has the methods, etc. from the inheritor class `A<T, N>` and does not actually inherit from the `A<char, 0>` specialized template instance that it needs to and thus I have no access to all the methods and data in the "base" class of `A<char, 0>`.

Has anyone else tried to get SWIG to handle this?  Successfully?  Is there a command line param that I can pass to SWIG that will make things work (and stop it from crashing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see to solve your problem is to stop being so fancy that you confuse the other languages, by being fancier **within** C++:

```
template<typename T>
struct A0_impl;
template<typename T, typename N>
struct A_impl;

template<typename T, int N>
struct A_helper {
  typedef A_impl<T,N> type;
};
template<typename T>
struct A_helper<T,0> {
  typedef A0_impl<T> type;
};

template<typename T, int N=0>
using A = typename A_helper<T,N>::type;

template<typename T>
struct A0_impl {
  A0_impl() : mFoo(nullptr)    {}
  virtual ~A0_impl()        {}

  T* getFoo() { return mFoo; }
private:
  T* mFoo;
};
template<typename T, typename N>
struct A_impl:A0_impl<T> {
  A_impl() : A0_impl<T>(), mBar(N) {}
  virtual ~A_impl() {}

  int getBar() const { return mBar; }

protected:
  int mBar;
};
template<typename T>
struct A_impl<T,0>:A0_impl<T> {
  A_impl() : A0_impl<T>() {}
  virtual ~A_impl() {}
  // possibly inherit other constructors from A0_impl
};
```

this gives you C++ code that behaves nearly exactly like your version, but does away with that descend-from-specialization issue that you believe is causing your problems.

Basically I replaced your `A<T,0>` specialization with `A0_impl`, and the `template` alias `A<T,N>` now maps to either `A_impl<T,N>` or `A0_impl<T>` depending on if `N` is `0` or not.

The `A` `template` alias is optional, as you could instead have `A0_impl` be called `AnySizedA` and `A_impl` be called `FixedSizeA`, and instead of specializing `A<T,0>` to do something simply ban it.

Comment: As it turns out, this is _basically_ the way that I ended up solving it - renaming A<T,0> to a different class name.   The only problem there is that I then had to go through the rest of the codebase and replace all the method params of A<T,0> with the name of the new base class.  Frustrating that I had to make so many code changes just to satisfy SWIG.  Luckily, I did have access to the libraries source code and could make changes.